# 'function' object has no attribute 'apply'

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a data frame df , which has a column 'query' having text data.

I am trying to clean text data  with the help of apply function. But getting the above error. My code is:

```
def _remove_noise(input_text):
    input_text = str(input_text).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    input_text = str(input_text).replace(",", "")
    return input_text
```

when I am calling the above function using the apply function as below:

```
df['query1'] = df.query.apply(_remove_noise)
```

It is throwing the error as :

> 'function' object has no attribute 'apply'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) is pandas function, so need `[]` for select column `query`:

```
df['query1'] = df['query'].apply(_remove_noise)
```

---

[`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) is used for filtering, like `df.query('col == 1')`, so if use `df.query.apply` it chain `query` and `apply` functions and error is raised.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jezrael, it is working. But why is df.query not working. query is one of the column of dataframe, I have tried it previously, and it worked fine

Comment: Probably because 'query' is s reserved word, reserved for the function called that way. It's not the same a a column called, say, 'country' or something like that.

Comment: @SurenderSingh - Because [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) is used for filtering, like `df.query('col == 1')`, so if use `df.query.apply` it chain `query` and `apply` functions and error is raised. so need alternative selection by `['query']` - this is general solution for selecting columns

Comment: Thanks Itamar Mushkin and @jezrael for the explanations. Yes, you are right